# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes with visual artifacts

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

I recently changed my GPU for a Radeon RX 580 (I was using a GTX 750Ti), and when using that new GPU, I am having freezes with visual artifacts on the screen (often quickly after getting in a session or some minutes later). These artifacts most of the time start by being either some sort of red forms or colored squares, then the screen turns to some random colors (see the pictures below).

I have done some troubleshooting so far and this is the information I gathered so far:

- This happens on Ubuntu 20.04, Pop!_OS 20.04 (which is Ubuntu based), but not on Debian 10, thus I assume it is a Ubuntu related issue (these were all tested with GNOME) Ubuntu and Pop! were both tested with X11 and Wayland, both didn't fix the issue.
- I don't think it is hardware related as I have a dual boot with a Windows install and I experienced absolutely no issues with that GPU on Windows so far
- The three distros I tried were all tried on live USB (note that I have a Pop! install on an HDD and it has the same issue)
- Everything works fine with the GTX 750Ti
- I believe Debian didn't have the amdgpu firmware or failed to load them (or at least I think I read so during its start-up), didn't notice such messages/warnings on the 2 others
- I believe I already had something similar years ago with Linux Mint, but that is a vague memory and it definitely isn't really relevant here.

Link to example pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

EDIT:
Here are some of the command outputs as asked

sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 2202
       date: 07/14/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 29
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 0
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_A1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/8GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 1
          serial: F0A2F235
          slot: DIMM_A2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a)Project-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-07-09 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 4809fcb62f445aaa3ae919f7f6c3cc7d156ea57a) [empty]
          product: Unknown
          vendor: Unknown
          physical id: 2
          serial: Unknown
          slot: DIMM_B1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/8GX
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 3
          serial: E9A2F229
          slot: DIMM_B2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 2c
       slot: L1 - Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2d
       slot: L2 - Cache
       size: 3MiB
       capacity: 3MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 2e
       slot: L3 - Cache
       size: 32MiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
```

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       865Mi        14Gi       8.0Mi       565Mi        14Gi
Swap:         1.0Gi          0B       1.0Gi
```

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

Comment: Did you install drivers for the Radeon RX 580?

Comment: @heynnema yes I did install the drivers for it, and it didn't fix the issues

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema The command returns "2202", it is a self-assembled computer, the motherboard is an Asus PRIME B540M-A, the CPU is an AMD Ryzen 5 3600, I don't know if the other components will make a difference but feel free to ask any of them. And thanks for your involvement!

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`, and tell me exactly what brand/model RAM DIMMs you have installed. Also see my initial answer.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

Asus PRIME B540M-A

Your BIOS is current at version 2202.

**Memory**

Ryzen processors have notorious problems with RAM.

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #1:**

Note: RAM was overclocked. Set back to default and am running `memtest` now.

Even though you have 16G RAM, your swap is a bit small. Let's bump it to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Verify this line in /etc/fstab...

```
/swapfile    none    swap    sw      0   0
```

**Update #2:**

`memtest` ran fine on the standard-clocked RAM.

**Update #3:**

See the video card driver 20.30 update at https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580 released on 7/30/2020. It supports Ubuntu 20.04.1.

**Update #4:**

Radeon 20.30 video driver fails to install on Pop_OS! but installs fine on Ubuntu.

Comment: The RAM model I have is HX432C16FB3K2 (from Kingston/HyperX), 2 * 8GB. I must say I set overclocking on my RAM in the BIOS in order to have the advertised 3200MHz frequency, but I set  it back to default because of what you wrote. (I am currently doing a memtest and will give the results when it ends)

Comment: The memtest ended with no errors, passing all tests. I increased the swap as told.

Comment: @emithethief Are the visual artifacts gone now? If so, we can assume that the overclocked RAM caused the problem, yes?

Comment: The visual artifacts and crashes are still not gone unfortunately. I appreciate your help still!

Comment: @emithethief Is the slot where the video card is plugged overclocked? Is your CPU overclocked? Can you check and see if there's a firmware update for the video card? Can you try a different slot? It sure looks like a video driver or video card problem.

Comment: I haven't changed any overclocking settings for the CPU or video card slot, so they shouldn't be overclocked. I cannot try a different slot for the GPU because I only have one on my motherboard. I am not sure how to check for GPU firmwares update (sorry, please bear with me), and I might mistake firmware and driver, so I prefer not to say "my drivers are up-to-date" when it could be irrelevant.

Comment: @emithethief See the driver update at https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-580  released on 7/30/2020.

Comment: I did install the drivers (or tried to), an issue I just had is dpkg returns "Errors were encountered while processing: amdgpu-dkms amdgpu" (note that I already tried to install the drivers another time and I had other issues with it I can't remember, also the installation script only works for ubuntu, mint, and debian, if you have a distro based on of these you have to modify the script to allow yours, which I did). The issues are not gone after installing the latest driver

Comment: @emithethief  I just downloaded the 20.30 driver, and I don't see any files that need modifying. Uninstall the current driver using either `amdgpu-uninstall` or `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`. You should be using `./amdgpu-install -y` to install the non-Pro version. Secure Boot should be disabled in your BIOS. Try again.

Comment: The amdgpu-install script requires to be modified for me as I am using Pop! which is a Ubuntu-based distro and not Ubuntu itself, and reports itself as pop and not ubuntu in /etc/os-release (which is read in the function os_release() of the install script). I reinstalled the driver again just to try and I still have the same issue at the end of the install (and the crashes+visual artifacts aren't fixed). Thank you still for your perseverance. I tried installing the drivers on an original Ubuntu install: it installs fine, but still doesn't prevent the crashes and visual artifacts coming along

Comment: @emithethief Did the install fail with the same amdgpu-dkms amdgpu error message? Did you turn off Secure Boot? I'd go back to the other video card.

Comment: The install on Pop indeed failed with the same error abiut amdgpu-dkms amdgpu. Secure boot was already off. I am considering contacting AMD and/or getting another GPU, wondering if mine is defective. Thank you still for your help, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: @emithethief Also, it's important to identify that you're using Pop_OS up front, not Ubuntu... and as you can see... the driver doesn't install on Pop, but does on real Ubuntu.