# How can I make my Radeon RX 570 work in Ubuntu 20.04? It gives visual artifacts and frequently freezes

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, radeon, visual-artifacts

I am experiencing the same sort of problems as have been mentioned in [other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265799/ubuntu-20-04-freezes-with-visual-artifacts) on this forum:

When I plug anything into my Radeon RX 570 video card, I get visual artifacts and freezes usually within minutes of working.  (Most notably, my 2 monitors.)

I chose that post as an example because it has representative examples of what I am experiencing; especially the third picture.

Initially I had no problems.  Then I tried to install "League of Legends" via Lutris, and got a crash.  (No overheating, though.  Nothing ever went above 50C.)  I have since uninstalled and reformatted (see below), but nothing has helped. If I try to use the video card, I get overwhelming artifacts and often freezes. (Although if YouTube is on, it continues playing audio. And occasionally I will see something resembling a mouse pointer, but I cannot click on anything or open a terminal or issue a command via alt+F2.

Just before the overwhelming artifacts, there is usually a bit of screen tearing in the upper left of my left monitor for 3-10 seconds.  I cannot click on anything during this time.

Things I have tried / verified:

1. I am almost certainly not overheating. No fans are ever blocked, and "System Profiler and Benchmark" (as well as PSensor) tell me that nothing that they are able to detect (in either the CPU or GPU) is ever going over even 50C.  (Usually everything is around 35C.)  I have no reason to distrust them.  PSensor doesn't detect the GPU, but I mention it anyway.
2. I am not overclocking anything, according to the BIOS.
3. It almost certainly isn't the cables.  The cables from the card to the monitor are brand new DisplayPort cables from Amazon Basics, and as I mention in #7, they work fine as long as they're not plugged into the card. This tells me it's the card, not those cables.  As for the card itself and the cables in the case, I got the satisfying click from every cable that plugs in.  Also, the cards worked without issue for a few days, whereas if it had been a seating issue, it seems like it ought to have been a problem nonstop from the moment I began to use my computer.
4. I have tried multiple reformats / clean installs of 20.04 and 20.10.  This has not helped.
5. As per [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/amd-radeon-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation), I've installed the PPA third-party repository and the proprietary AMDGPU-PRO drivers.  This did not help.  I also got the drivers [directly from AMD](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-570), and followed their instructions.  This did not help.
6. It seems that I can make this happen on command (rather than waiting) by letting the screen turn off and then back on, as per the Settings > Power > Blank Screen option.  It does seem helpful to know that it is, at least, repeatable in this fashion.
7. If I plug my monitors only into the motherboard, everything works fine with the onboard Intel graphics chipset.  It appears that the amdgpu drivers are loading and that the card is there, but it at least doesn't crash my system (so far).

Here's a link to my hardware in use right now:

https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=8118fd6863

Because of what I have read in similar threads, I am going to preemptively post the terminal results of some commands here:

The results of:
sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 0811
       date: 06/12/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 40
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 32GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 0
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-16GVK
          vendor: G-Skill
          physical id: 1
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelA-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 2
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: F4-3200C16-16GVK
          vendor: G-Skill
          physical id: 3
          serial: 00000000
          slot: ChannelB-DIMM2
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 4d
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 4e
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 4f
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:7fd20000-7fd23fff
```

The results of:
free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       2.4Gi        26Gi       659Mi       2.2Gi        27Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

The results of:
sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

The results of:
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

```
0811
```

(This was a self-assembled computer from parts that Computer Part Picker verified were indeed compatible with each other and Ubuntu.)

Please, help.